# How to access function from child component to parent component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular12

Trying to access the remove function from child component(chips-autocomplete-example). But not able to access it in app.component. When i click the close (X) icon, i want to get the value of that. For example, if i click the Apple close icon, i want to get the Apple text in the alert. Same like for others(Lemon, Lime, Orange, Strawberry) I am doing this from the app.component ts file. But not working. How to resolve this?

app.component.ts:

```
  removeClick(removeval) {
    alert(removeval);
  }
```

app.component.html:

```
<chips-autocomplete-example
  (removed)="removeClick(fruit)"
></chips-autocomplete-example>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbrx2p-k89gvp?file=app.component.ts

Comment: Looks like you're missing some of the HTML, see https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples#chips-autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I'm understand your problem correctly, but from child do parent (in the easiest way) you can use
`@Output() removed = new EventEmitter<string>();` and in remove function add `this.removed.emit(fruit)` in child and then in parent

```
<chips-autocomplete-example
  (removed)="removeClick($event)"
></chips-autocomplete-example>
```

Comment: Can you edit my stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbrx2p-q6t4sx 
you stackblitz was almost good ;) just replace in `app.component.html` 
`removeClick(fruit)` with `removeClick($event)`